# Проблема с выводом в файл C++

Tags: c++, циклы, вывод, while, файловый-ввод-вывод

Написал программу, которая находит n-количество расчетов для eps-введенного и всё это нужно вывести в файл,но программа работает, а вывод в файл нет. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
long int J(long double n, unsigned int i) {
    if (i == 0) return 1;
    if (i > 1) n = n * pow(n, i - 1);
    return n;
}
    long int fact(int i) {
        if (i == 0) return 1;
        else return i * fact(i - 1);
    }
    int main()
    {
                setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
        ofstream resultat;
        unsigned int i = 1;
        long double x, J1 = 1, J2 = 0.0;
        float eps;
        resultat.open("lab3.txt", ios::out);
        cout << " n 4^i*i^2\n";
        cout << " ∑ —------— *(x^i)\n";
        cout << " i=1 (i+2)!\n";
        cout << "Вводим эпсилон(с которым сравниваем)\n";
        cin >> eps;
        cout << "Вводим x\n";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "\n";
        while (J1 <= eps) {
            J1 = J2 + ((pow(4, i)*J(i, 2)) / (fact(i + 2))*pow(x, i));
            cout << "i = " << i << " " << "(4^i * i^2) = " << pow(4, i)*pow(i, 2) << " " << "(fact(i + 2)) =" << fact(i + 2) << " "
                << "(J1) = " << J1 << "\n";
            i++;
        }
            if (i >= 27)
            {
                cout << "Значение i перешло диапазон нашей программы, дальнейший расчет невозможен > 0\n";
                cout << i - 2;
                resultat << "Эпсилон =" << J1;
                resultat << "\nN =" << i - 2;
                resultat.close();
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Минимальное n, для которого очередное слагаемое не превышает eps > 0\n";
                cout << i - 2;
                return 0;
                resultat << "Эпсилон =" << J1;
                resultat << "\nN =" << i - 2;
                resultat.close();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скажите, а чего вы ждете?

```
return 0;
resultat << "Эпсилон =" << J1;
resultat << "\nN =" << i - 2;
```

Это примерно как провести друга до двери, еще и дать пинка (`return` - завершение работы), а потом удивляться, а что это он свое пиво, на столе стоящее, после этого не допил? :)

Скажите, это точно ваш код? Неужели вы такое просмотрели?

Comment: Да это мой код. Спасибо!

Comment: Ну, тогда будьте внимательнее. И даже если не умеете пользваться отладчиком, можно просто добавить отладочный вывод - например, `cout << "Вывод в файл\n";` перед/после `resultat <<` и посмотреть, а вывод на экран есть? А если нет - то почему?